# How to set the content in an HttpResponse type?

Tags: java, http, response, httpresponse

My goal is to build a new `HttpResponse` out of an old one.
My attempt is this:

```
String headers = dbh.getResponseHeaders(url);
InputStream content = dbh.getResponseContent(url);
final HttpResponse cachedResponseToReturn = response;
cachedResponseToReturn.setHeaders(null);
final StringEntity sEntity = new StringEntity(content.toString());   ////these lines
cachedResponseToReturn.setEntity(sEntity);  ////these lines
final LinkedList<String[]> headersList = divideStringToAllTheHeaders(headers);
for (int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); ++i)
   cachedResponseToReturn.addHeader(headersList.get(i)[0], headersList.get(i)[1]);
```

By the way, the 'response' variable is an HttpResponse to initialize the new response. I only use it to initialization.
In other words, how do I set the content of the `HttpResponse` type that I have?

tnx, Itamar.

Comment: `final HttpResponse cachedResponseToReturn = response;`. Where does `response` come from?

Comment: It is just an http response that I previously got from the webserver. I use this variable in order to initialize the new response that I want to build.

Comment: If you assign it like that, all your calls will affect the original response object you got.